# Javascript: Multiplicative Persistence Problem Proposed Solution Execution Timing Out

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have the following problem:

Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

```
function persistence(num) {

  let count = 0; 
  let numStr = num.toString(); 

   if (numStr.length === 1){
     return 0
   } 

   if (numStr.length === 2){
     while (numStr.length > 1){
       count += 1
       numStr = (Number(numStr[0])*Number(numStr[1])).toString() 
     }
   }

   if (numStr.length === 3){
     while (numStr.length > 1){
       count += 1
       numStr = (Number(numStr[0])*Number(numStr[1])*Number(numStr[2])).toString() 
     }
   }

   return count 
}

persistence(999) //solution 4
```

I'm getting "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)" error.  I know there's different ways to tackle this problem but I want to know specifically what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I don't see any reason for different `if` statments

Comment: Your "3" case assumes that the string is always 3 digits long in the loop; it won't be, so you end up with `NaN` and that will always be `NaN` (and more than one character long).

Comment: First iteration of your while loop you get `9*9*9 = 729`. Then `7*2*9 = 126`, then `1*2*6 = 12`, then `1*2*undefined = NaN`, then `'N'*'a'*'N' = NaN`, then `'N'*'a'*'N' = NaN`, then `'N'*'a'*'N' = NaN`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working because you are always adding `str[2]` to the final result.

```
999 > 729 > 126 > 12 > 2
```

So here you see at one loop number becomes `12` and `str[2]` is `undefined` and it will be `NaN` so loop never ends.

A simple way is using `reduce()` inside `while` and no need to convert the to `Number()` while multiplying

```js
function persistence(num) {

  let count = 0; 
  num = String(num);
  while(num.length > 1){
    count++;
    num = String([...num].reduce((ac,a) => a * ac,1));
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(persistence(999))
```

Comment: Good answer, but please, please, don't use `x + ''` instead of `String(x)`

Comment: @georg I changed that. I also want to the reason for using `String(x)`  not `x + ''`

Comment: @georg `x + ''` is the usual way to coerce to a string in JavaScript. There is not a good reason to use the String constructor very often. `num.toString()` would be better but just concatenating with an empty string is arguably the best.

Comment: @Paulpro: `String(x)` is not a constructor.

Comment: @georg [Yes, it is](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-string-constructor). (and: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-constructor-properties-of-the-global-object). You can call it without `new` but `String` is still a constructor no whether you use it as one or not.

Comment: @MaheerAli: what `x + ''` does, is this, literally: `String(x) + ''`. Is there any point in doing "convert to a string and then add an empty string" when you can just do "convert to a string"? Besides, `x + ''` looks ugly, especially when applied to a long expression. Thanks for fixing!

Answer (score 1):

With recursive function you can do it easily :

Just add a new args `count` (how many time this function as been called) and recall it while the result length is more than 1

```js
function persistence(num, count) {
  count = count || 0; 
  let numStr = num.toString(); 
  
  if (numStr.length === 1) {
    return count
  } 
  let new_num = numStr.split('').reduce((acc, val) => {
    return acc * val
  }, 1)
  return persistence(new_num, count + 1) 
}

console.log("99", persistence(99))
console.log("999", persistence(999))
console.log("99999", persistence(99999))
```

Comment: You could also skip the extra parameter and `return persistence(new_num) + 1;` with `return 0` in the basement case instead of `return count`.

Comment: No. because `return 0` will assume that's the first time you're calling this function. (or I didn't understand)

Comment: @Paulpro the way it's written it's at least possible to be tail-call optimized (though most JS runtimes don't do that)

Comment: @Arthur If `numStr.length === 1` the first time you call the function then 0 is the correct answer.

Comment: It would look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/n64co98b/ and always gives the same output as your function, but is a bit easier to understand in my opinion, since each recursive call is just calculating the persistence of the next number.